# Java 8 stream agregate generic list to map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get myself used with the Java 8 stream functionality by applying it in a small home project. Recently I had the issue reproduced below and despite the fact I understand what the issue is I  could not find the fix. I am posting it here hoping to get some explanations and the correct solution.

```
public class GroupingByStreamTest {
    class Double<A, B> {
        A a;
        B b;

        public Double(A a, B b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    class Triple<A, B, C> extends Double<A, B> {
        C c;

        public Triple(A a, B b, C c) {
            super(a, b);
            this.c = c;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGroupToMap() throws Exception {
        List<Triple<String, String, String>> listOfTriples = asList(
            new Triple<>("a-1", "b-1", "c-1"),
            new Triple<>("a-1", "b-2", "c-2"),
            new Triple<>("a-1", "b-3", "c-3"),
            new Triple<>("a-2", "b-4", "c-4"),
            new Triple<>("a-2", "b-5", "c-5"));

        // This code below compiles and executes OK. If I put a   breakpoint
        // in my EDI I can even see the expected Map being created. However
        // if you uncomment the line below and comment the one after it the
        // code will no longer compile. 

        // Map<String, List<Double<String, String>>> myMap =
        Map<Object, List<Double<Object, Object>>> myMap =
        listOfTriples.stream().collect(groupingBy(t -> t.a,
            mapping((Triple t) -> new Double<>(t.b, t.c),toList())));

        assertEquals(2, myMap.size());
    }
}
```

The compile error I got is

```
Error:(49, 39) java: incompatible types: inference variable A has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: java.lang.String
lower bounds: java.lang.Object
```

Comment: Map<String, List<Double<String, String>>> myMap =
  // Map<Object, List<Double<Object, Object>>> myMap =
  listOfTriples.stream()
    .collect(
      Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.a,
        Collectors.mapping((Triple<String, String, String> t) -> new Double<>(t.b, t.c), Collectors.toList())));

Comment: You are using a raw type `Triple` parameter in your lambda, in the `mapping` collector. Try with
`Triple<String, String, String>`, or even simpler simply just use `mapping(t -> new Double<>(...))`, the compiler will infer it's a `Triple<String, String, String>` for you. (You're no specifying it in the `groupingBy(t -> t.a` by the way).

Comment: You shouldn’t name your class `Double` as it conflicts with `java.lang.Double`, that’s a recipe for future problems. Name it `Pair` or such alike. And `Triple extends Double` in another code smell. A triple is not a pair, you will notice the problems once you attempt to add correct `equals` and `hashCode` methods to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the raw type of `Triple` in your mapping.

if you adjust your code like this:

```
Map<String, List<Double<String, String>>> myMap =  
listOfTriples
.stream()
.collect(
  groupingBy(t -> t.a, 
    mapping((Triple<String, String, String> t) -> new Double<>(t.b, t.c), toList())
));
```

it should work

Comment: That came so fast and so correct. At some stage I tried this too but I might have broken it in a different place and wrongly concluded it was no the right way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use raw types. Either drop the type specification for `t` at all:

```
Map<Object, List<Double<Object, Object>>> myMap =
        listOfTriples.stream().collect(groupingBy(t -> t.a,
            mapping(t -> new Double<>(t.b, t.c),toList())));
```

Or specify its type fully:

```
Map<Object, List<Double<Object, Object>>> myMap =
        listOfTriples.stream().collect(groupingBy(t -> t.a,
            mapping((Triple<String, String, String> t) -> new Double<>(t.b, t.c),toList())));
```